# custom check all checkbox issue with datatables framework

Tags: jquery, datatables

When i select manually items checkbox and export item using CSV button its working fine but if click check all checkbox from top simply datatables framework not garbing all checkbox as selected. my goal data export should work with check all and manual whatever i select. How can i fix it? any idea?......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Real App</title>

 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<style>
    table.dataTable tbody td.select-checkbox, table.dataTable tbody th.select-checkbox {
      position: static !important;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
                <table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap no-footer dtr-inline dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable-responsive_info" style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                            <tr role="row" class="pointer odd">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="1159" /><br />

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img id="ebayImg" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/132148971575-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/132148971575-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qhWQ3VG7L._AC_US218_.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qhWQ3VG7L._AC_US218_.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" width="30%">
                                    <h5><b><a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/132148971575" id="titleText" value="LG Stylo 3 16GB LTE Smartphone for Boost Mobile - New" id="linkText" target="_blank">LG Stylo 3 16GB LTE Smartphone for Boost Mobile - New</a></b></h5>

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left" width="30%">
                                    <h5><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y6J869C" id="" target="_blank">LG Stylo 3 - Prepaid - Carrier Locked - Boost Mobile</a></h5>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1">
                                    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y6J869C" target="_blank">B06Y6J869C</a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 119.99
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 119.99
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    $ -17.7
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    0
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">

                                    <a class="btnWatchList" value="1159" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a class="deleteBulkItem" value="1159"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr role="row" class="pointer odd">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="1158" /><br />

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img id="ebayImg" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/142129917740-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/142129917740-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31qQlocEU8L._AC_US218_.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31qQlocEU8L._AC_US218_.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" width="30%">
                                    <h5><b><a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/142129917740" id="titleText" value="HTC One A9 32GB Opal Silver for Boost Mobile &#194;– New" id="linkText" target="_blank">HTC One A9 32GB Opal Silver for Boost Mobile &#194;– New</a></b></h5>

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left" width="30%">
                                    <h5><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M0OBVW2" id="" target="_blank">HTC One A9 - Retail Packaging (Boost Mobile) - Carrier Locked - Opal Silver</a></h5>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1">
                                    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M0OBVW2" target="_blank">B01M0OBVW2</a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 120.91
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 109.99
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    $ -27.17
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    0
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">

                                    <a class="btnWatchList" value="1158" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a class="deleteBulkItem" value="1158"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr role="row" class="pointer odd">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="1157" /><br />

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img id="ebayImg" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/252503208819-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/252503208819-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-dHInCIRL._AC_US218_.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51-dHInCIRL._AC_US218_.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" width="30%">
                                    <h5><b><a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/252503208819" id="titleText" value="Fireplace Fence Baby Safety Fence Hearth Gate Pet Cat Dog BBQ Metal Fire Gate " id="linkText" target="_blank">Fireplace Fence Baby Safety Fence Hearth Gate Pet Cat Dog BBQ Metal Fire Gate </a></b></h5>

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left" width="30%">
                                    <h5><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075YR25TM" id="" target="_blank">JAXPETY Adjustable Weight Bench Barbell Incline Flat Lifting Workout Body Press Home Gym</a></h5>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1">
                                    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075YR25TM" target="_blank">B075YR25TM</a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 71.99
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 52.99
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    $ -26.98
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    0
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">

                                    <a class="btnWatchList" value="1157" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a class="deleteBulkItem" value="1157"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr role="row" class="pointer odd">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" class="checkItem" name="checkItem" value="1152" /><br />

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img id="ebayImg" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/252193780226-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/252193780226-0-1/s-l250/p.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0" width="5%">
                                    <ul class="enlarge">
                                        <!--We give the list a class so that we can style it seperately from other unordered lists-->
                                        <!--First Image-->
                                        <li>
                                            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41T3BwQbIkL._AC_US218_.jpg" height="60px" width="60px">
                                            <span>
                                                <!--span contains the popup image-->
                                                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41T3BwQbIkL._AC_US218_.jpg">
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" width="30%">
                                    <h5><b><a href="http://www.ebay.com/itm/252193780226" id="titleText" value="Adjustable Indoor Solid Wood Construction Pet Fence Gate Free Standing Dog Gate" id="linkText" target="_blank">Adjustable Indoor Solid Wood Construction Pet Fence Gate Free Standing Dog Gate</a></b></h5>

                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left" width="30%">
                                    <h5><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075BHLJN7" id="" target="_blank">JAXPETY Electric Knife Sharpener 2 Stage Kitchen Blade Sharpening System New</a></h5>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1">
                                    <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075BHLJN7" target="_blank">B075BHLJN7</a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 17.59
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="7%">
                                    $ 44.99
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    $ 20.58
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
                                    0
                                </td>
                                <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">

                                    <a class="btnWatchList" value="1152" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a class="deleteBulkItem" value="1152"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                    </tbody>
                    <thead>
                        <tr role="row">
                            <th class="column-title">Check all: <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" class="chkAll"></th>

                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 60px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Ebay Image</th>
                            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 60px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending">Amazon Image</th>

                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">Ebay Title</th>

                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">Amazon Title</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">ASIN</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">Amazon price</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">eBay price</th>

                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px; text-align:center;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">Profit</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px; text-align:center;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending">Sales</th>
                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 771px;" aria-label="Product name: activate to sort column ascending"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>


<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Remodal/dist/remodal.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Remodal/dist/remodal-default-theme.css" />
<script src="/Remodal/dist/remodal.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/datatables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vendors/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script> -->

<script>
    var type_id;
    $('select').change(function () {
        type_id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                //    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
                {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: 'copy',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6],
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'csv',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6],
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6],
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: 'pdf',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [5, 3, 4, 7, 6],
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                },

            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets: 0,
                checkboxes: {
                    selectRow: true
                }
            }],
            select: {
                style: 'multi',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            order: [[1, 'asc']]

        });
    });

//checkbox selection process

$("#checkAll").click(function () {//check and uncheck all function
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});

//checkbox selection process ends

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the boxes is not quite enough, you need to select the rows as well:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {//check and uncheck all function
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  table.rows().select(this.checked); // < add this
});
```

All this inside $(document).ready of course, or you won't have the table var.

Comment: Can you implement it on my full code? I tried but even checkbox select all was selected all data not exports with datatables framework. thanks in advance